# Google Colaboratory data table display max 20 columns

Tags: google-colaboratory

I find data table display useful, but I have a warning ***"Warning: Total number of columns (28) exceeds max_columns (20) limiting to first max_columns"***: is there a way to go beyond?
Thanks for any suggestion
Best

Answer (score 16):

You can increase the limit

```
from google.colab.data_table import DataTable
DataTable.max_columns = 30
```

Then it should display as you want.

Comment: And it doesn't :(

Comment: @pedrouan switch to interactive table (there is a button for it after you display the table) and it will work

Answer (score -2):

You can use the 'set_option' method in pandas to change the maximum columns to be displayed.

```
import pandas as pd

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 30)
```

Now you can display the the dataframe which will display more than 20 columns in colab.